# Turn off Visual Studio Find Default Selection

Tags: visual-studio-2010, replace, find

When I Ctrl+Shift+F in VS2010, it puts whatever is near my cursor in the "Find what:" box - this is very irritating and never what I want.

Is there any way to make it default instead to the last thing I searched for?

Comment: It also selects everything in the box, so you should be able to just type over it as if there was nothing there..? You can also hit the down arrow to load the most recent search. I don't know of a way to make it default to that though.

Comment: I had the opposite problem, this option was somehow unchecked I and I prefer the behavior. Not sure how it got unchecked, but I'm glad this question pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Find and Replace -> Automatically populate Find What with text from the editor

If you uncheck this option it will default to the last thing you searched for.

[image: Automatically populate Find What with text from the editor]

Comment: I wanted to get rid of searching the word under the caret *when selection is empty*, and that did it. Too bad it also disables searching selection *when it is not empty*. They should add an option to enable just that so it works like VS code (and same-type editors like Atom and Sublime Text).

Comment: After the new installation was marked but did not work. I've removed my check and saved and I've rechecked it and it works!

Comment: Cannot find this option in Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

an nice. Glad i found this...

two work arounds i figured out...  if you do want to search in selected text only sometimes but not all the time...

1. Mouse: Click back on the page and ctrl+A  (its faster than having to grab the mouse and clicking the tiny drop down.)
2. Keyboard only: Well you cant technically do this, with any one command from http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/14/   but you can do this.

while find is active, hit
   alt+F6
to get out of find and then hit
   esc
to activate the document then 
   ctrl+A
to search the whole document

I am glad to find how to turn this off, but i am used to this keyboard commands now.  So maybe i will leave it on.

if you don't learn to use the escape key in VS, especially for intellisense you are going to seriously drive yourself crazy.